# Mockito not working on update/create in RESTcontroller

Tags: java, rest, testing, mockito

I'm trying to write some tests using Mockito and I managed to write them for findAll and delete operations but for the create and update, they won't work.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RentedControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private RentedService rentalService;

    @Mock
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Mock
    private ClientService clientService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RentedController rentalController;

    @InjectMocks
    private MovieController movieController;

    @InjectMocks
    private ClientController clientController;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getMovies() throws Exception {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
        movies.add(mock(Movie.class));
//        System.out.println(movies.toString());
        when(movieService.findAll()).thenReturn(movies);
////        System.out.println(movieService.findAll().toString());
        MoviesDto response = movieController.getMovies();
        assertEquals("should be 1 movie", 1, response.getMovies().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void updateMovie() throws Exception {
        Movie movie = new Movie(2,"Lotr",0, "dir2", 2003);
        MovieDto movieDto = mock(MovieDto.class);
        System.out.println(movie.toString());
        when(movieService.updateMovie(anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(movie);
//        Movie m = new Movie();
//        m = movieService.updateMovie(2,"Lotrrrrr",0, "dir2", 2003);
//        System.out.println(m.toString());
        Map<String, MovieDto> map = movieController.updateMovie(2, movieDto);
        System.out.println(map.toString());
        assertEquals("Title should be Lots", "Lotr", map.get("movie").getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void createMovie() throws Exception {
        Movie movie = new Movie(2,"Lotr",0, "dir2", 2003);
        MovieDto movieDto = mock(MovieDto.class);
        when(movieService.createMovie(anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(movie);
        Map<String, MovieDto> map = movieController.createMovie(movieDto);
        assertEquals("Title should be Lotr", "Lotr", map.get("movie").getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteMovie() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity response = movieController.deleteMovie(1);
        assertEquals("Http status should be OK", HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

So the line "when(movieService.update....) work's just fine. I tested it with the write lines as you can see in the code and it works. The problem is here

```
Map<String, MovieDto> map = movieController.updateMovie(2, movieDto);
```

I gives me NullPointerException inside that method. The method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/movies/{movieId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = CatalogMediaType.API_JSON)
    public Map<String, MovieDto> updateMovie(@PathVariable final Integer movieId,
                                             @RequestBody final MovieDto movieDto) {
        log.trace("updateMovie: movieId={} movieDto={}", movieId, movieDto);

        Movie movie = movieService.updateMovie(movieId, movieDto.getMovie().getName(), movieDto.getMovie().getNumberofrentals(), movieDto.getMovie().getDirector(), movieDto.getMovie().getYear());

        Map<String, MovieDto> movieDtoMap = new HashMap<>();
        movieDtoMap.put("movie", new MovieDto(movie));
        log.trace("updateMovie: movieDtoMap={}", movieDtoMap);

        return movieDtoMap;
    }
```

The application itself works perfectly, the problem arises only when runing the mockito tests.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ro.ubb.stcatalog.web.controller.MovieController.updateMovie(MovieController.java:41)
    at ro.ubb.stcatalog.web.controller.RentedControllerTest.updateMovie(RentedControllerTest.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

2016-05-26T23:51:52,845 TRACE [main]: MovieController                      - createMovie: moviesDto=Mock for MovieDto, hashCode: 825249556 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ro.ubb.stcatalog.web.controller.MovieController.createMovie(MovieController.java:54)
    at ro.ubb.stcatalog.web.controller.RentedControllerTest.createMovie(RentedControllerTest.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I don't really understand what the problem is if the findAll and delete work just fine... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the mocking of `MovieDto` class is causing the `NPE`, as your controller is expecting a few params to be present in the DTO, which are not being set by the `mock()`, such as `movieDto.getMovie().getName()`.

Create a `MovieDto` object from scratch with all the required params, or set the params post mocking, and you should be fine.

The following should work.

```
@Test
    public void updateMovie() throws Exception {
        Movie movie = new Movie(2,"Lotr",0, "dir2", 2003);
        MovieDto movieDto = mock(MovieDto.class);

        // Added the following line
        movieDto.setMovie(movie);

        System.out.println(movie.toString());
        when(movieService.updateMovie(anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(movie);
        Map<String, MovieDto> map = movieController.updateMovie(2, movieDto);
        System.out.println(map.toString());
        assertEquals("Title should be Lots", "Lotr", map.get("movie").getName());
    }
```

Comment: I dont really understand. MovieDto only has 1 parameter and that's a movie. And it also has the default constructor

Comment: @Melye77 then set the movie object to the MovieDto object, currently the movie object inside Movie DTO object is either null, or empty.

Comment: Ok this actually worked! I mocked a movie instead of a MovieDto an d passed that mock as a parameter to the MovieDto and that was it. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Yea I just had to wait a little cause it was too soon ^^

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some dependency for the MovieController isn't getting set.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ro.ubb.stcatalog.web.controller.MovieController.createMovie(MovieController.java:54)
```

Comment: But the movieController works for the other operations like delete and findAll...

Comment: The error sends me in the controller at the movieService.update line. I went in with the debugger and it fails there... but it should just send me the mock movie... I tested it with prints before

Comment: Are all the params to the movieService non null  - you may need to step thru the debugger here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate movieDto first. When you are doing get in the actual code its like you are doing get on a null which gives a NullPointer. And also Both values should be same. In when condition you are telling movieId as anyInt() and in the actual method call you are giving it as 2. That won't work. Both should be same as below.

```
when(movieService.updateMovie(**2**, anyString(), anyInt(), anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(movie);
        Map<String, MovieDto> map = movieController.updateMovie(**2**, movieDto);
```